# file force download

Tags: php

I want to force a download.. In IE I get an error but there are no problems in FF

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download\n");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");

echo 'test file';
```

Comment: Whats `application/force-download` for a mime-type? Where did you take this from?! Oo

Answer (score 5):

I just googled about your curious `application/force-download` mime type. I dont know, who did "invented" this, but it seems, that it just dont exists. See http://mimeapplication.org/force-download.html

This means, the IE probably dont like it. Use `application/octet-stream` instead. As far as I remember firefox opens a download dialog for every mime-type, that is either registered with "show download dialog", or it simply doesnt know. In this case FF probably doesnt know the type.

Comment: it works, but now I can't preset the filename... header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");

Comment: Dont know, if thats the reason for your behaviour, but dont put a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you , it works for me

```
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
flush();
readfile($filename);
exit;
```

you can add other headers if desired :)

Comment: In modern server code we should avoid `application/force-download`, this is an old hack.